# Does URL length cause page different page load times?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, performance, varnish

I have a JS/PHP application that has different page load times on different machines.

I have my main application which generates some HTML.

A single page PHP app along with some JavaScript which generates a URL, the URL is then used to load an iFrame (using jQuery). The URL has been upto 400 characters or more. Which pulls in content from the main app.

The way it works is when the single page PHP loads the JS takes any parameters and generates a URL, the target div for the content then displays a loading gif, jQuery creates an iFrame in the target div

```
$('<iframe>', {
  src: '/foo/' + param,
}).appendTo("#bar");
```

jQuery then waits for the iFrame to load, hide the loader and display the content

```
$('#bar').on('load', function() {
  $('#loading').hide();
  $('#container').show();
});
```

In production (which uses varnish) the page takes a really long to load on mobile devices and one of my dev machines, on another dev machine and my own laptop at home the page loads instantaneously.

I can't work out where the bottleneck is, do browsers take a long time to load an iframe with a long URL, or could this be a varnish issue?

With varnish disabled it takes too long to load a page.

Comment: The length of the URL should have very little impact on the page load time.

Comment: maybe these parameters make the server "think" harder (filtering / querying) affecting the response time

Comment: @Barmar OK good to know, thank you.

Comment: @Jossef Harush possibly, but the server requests for some devices is instant compared to an age on other devices.

Answer (score 0):

**Does URL length cause page different page load times?**

No. Each character in an URL may just be 1 byte. So, assuming an URL of 20 characters, unless you have a 19byte/sec download speed, you won't notice the difference.

100MB/s = 104857600 bytes/s